# will the applications of lower version of ubuntu work on higher one

Tags: application-finder

I am using ubuntu 14.04lts, not many applications are there for this. I think it will work. Please also recommend me some trusted website for getting applications for ubuntu 14.04 other than their official website, where only few are there in ubuntu 14.04 section.

Comment: "not many applications are there for this" what do you mean by this, what applications? And what software from older releaser you want to run? Please elaborate.

Comment: Ubuntu has one of the largest available range of software in the repositories and ppa. You may need to enable some repositories (universe, multiverse) - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: i recently intalled ubuntu and when i went on their website, there were different sections for different versions of ubuntu but in the section ubuntu 14.04 there were only few. so i thought maybe the applications from older versions could also work on the new one, maybe thats why there are only few. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

That is going to be a hit and miss situation. Yes, it will work for a lot of software. But if you do this with something that has a lot of dependencies you will pull those in too. And if it has a library installation might fail.

It works best if you can find a personal archive (that way you can supply the Ubuntu version yourself).

> Please also recommend me some trusted website for getting applications for ubuntu 14.04 other than their official website, where only few are there in ubuntu 14.04 section.

There is just one: [getdeb](http://www.getdeb.net/welcome/). It has 5x25+1=126 packages listed.

But be careful with non official websites. That is one of the reasons Windows has more problems then it should have: the ability to download and install anything from the web. Stick with the official packages if possible.